# spring-boot Kafka integration in docker using docker-compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to connect Kafka in spring boot inside Docker but it shows an error **"could not be established. Broker may not be available."**

Kafka and zookeeper server running successfully but I am unable to connect broker inside spring-boot.

here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
    - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
    - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  spring_boot:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

**application.yml** from Kafka producer

```
kafka:
  boot:
    server: kafka:9092
  topic:
    name: myTopic-kafkasender
server:
  port: 8081
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here

Comment: it can be the problem with your ports.. you can try to use 2181 inside your application.yml file for server: kafka:2181 insted of server: kafka:9092

Comment: @VikasSuryawanshi zookeeper running on 2181 port

Comment: Are you sure `${kafka.boot.server}` is the correct property?  I would expect to see something like `{spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}`.

Comment: @wjans yes it is custom

Comment: Are you sure it's actually trying to connect to `kafka:9092`?  If you have custom stuff in place, it seems important to mention in your question.

Comment: @wjans yes it is trying to connect kafka:9092

Comment: You never define KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT, but `kafka.bootstrap-servers` should be your spring property name, there's no other logical value that would be under "boot" in your config, so just flatten it

Comment: @Vikas 2181 is Zookeeper, which Kafka clients cannot be used to connect to

Comment: @OneCricketeer what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use the wurstmeister containers, but I'll repeat my comment, 1) `${kafka.boot.server}` matches no example spring-kafka code I've seen 2) You should add the environment variable I said to the wurstmeister container https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @OneCricketeer I will try this, thank you :)